# Gradle project sync failed on Android Studio 3.1.3 (2018)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, maven-metadata

Gradle project sync failed on Android Studio.
I tried to import other Gradle distributions on Android Studio via File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployement > Gradle > Use local gradle distribution

But still the same error message : Gradle project sync failed

Any solution ? (please refer to the attached picture)

[image]

[Error message 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXtbC.png)

Comment: As of my search, this repository [is discontinued and deprecated](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2). You should try another library instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using a [discontinued and deprecated](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2) library, where the [repository URL](https://s3.amazonaws.com/repo.commonsware.com) even can't find anything related to `cam2`, which is shown in your "Error message 2".

As of the `README` said in that repo,

> This library is discontinued and deprecated. New projects should look elsewhere, and existing projects should plan on migrating to something else.
>
> Options include:
>
> - Various other [open source camera libraries for Android](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/141), notably [CameraKit-Android](https://github.com/gogopop/CameraKit-Android) and [Fotoapparat](https://github.com/Fotoapparat/Fotoapparat)
> - using the Android SDK APIs (Camera and android.hardware.camera2.*) directly
>
> If you wish to continue exploring this library, [read on](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-cam2/blob/master/README-original.markdown).
>
> The issue tracker for this repository will be turned off on 1 December 2017. The repository itself will be made private on 1 September 2018.

You are told what to do after that, what you need to do is follow that.